# How do I keep a loop DRY when the initializer is also the loop setter?

Tags: javascript

It bugs me that I can't figure out a way to keep my code both readable and DRY (don't repeat yourself) for this basic loop type, where you initialize a value, and then do that same thing each time. It happens for reading files and the like all the time. I can obviously repeat the initializer, and sometimes clean it up into a function, but it bugs me! How do I do this cleanly?

FOR LOOP

```js
let headCount = 0;
for (
  let isHeads = Math.random() > 0.5; 
  isHeads; 
  isHeads = Math.random() > 0.5  // Duplicate
) {
  headCount++;
}
console.log(headCount);
```

WHILE LOOP

```js
let headCount = 0;
let isHeads = Math.random() > 0.5;
while (isHeads) {
  headCount++;
  isHeads = Math.random() > 0.5; // Duplicate
}
console.log(headCount);
```

DIFFICULT TO READ LOOP

I can obviously remove the variable name, but that hurts readability, and for something like reading a file, you can't see what the value was set to.

```js
let headCount = 0;
while (Math.random() > 0.5) {
  headCount++;
}
console.log(headCount);
```

For example, if you wanted to read the value, you'd need to put it into a variable somewhere:

```js
function rollDie() { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; }
function playGame() {
  let roll = rollDie();
  let score = 0;
  while (roll != 1) {
    console.log(`You rolled a ${roll}! Yay!`);
    score += roll;
    roll = rollDie(); //Duplicate
  }
  console.log(`Oh no you rolled a 1! Your score was ${score}`);
}
```

MY LINTER HATES ME LOOP

You can set a variable in the condition line, but every linter worth it's salt gets scared and generally underlines this in red:

```js
let headCount = 0;
let isHeads;
while (isHeads = Math.random() > 0.5) {
  headCount++;
}
console.log(headCount);
```

Comment: Please, easy on the ALL CAPS.

Comment: There’s nothing actually wrong with the last two options, maybe try double parenthesis to appease the linter? `while ((isHeads = Math.random() > 0.5))`

Comment: Also a `do while` loop probably works if you want to be explicit

Answer (score 2):

Make the coin tossing test a function, like `heads()` to remove that complexity and make it clear what you're doing. The "difficult to read loop" is actually the form you should be using, and is not difficult to read. That's extremely conventional and what I'd actually expect to see.

What you end up with is:

```js
function heads() {
  return Math.random() > 0.5;
}

function headsCount() {
  let count = 0;
  while (heads()) {
    count++;
  }

  return count;
}
```

Now you can just call it:

```js
console.log(headsCount());
```

Code like this is a lot easier to test since each function does one specific thing. You could, for example, verify your `heads()` function actually returns `true` 50% of the time, not 49.999995% or 50.000003% or whatever might be happening because of quirks of the RNG, because that function is exposed directly and has a *singular purpose*.

At the slight expense of readability, but technically more compact you can rewrite that `while` as a `for`:

```js
function headsCount() {
  let count;

  for (count = 0; heads(); ++count);

  return count;
}
```

That doesn't really help much, and is only presented here as an alternate form.

Comment: Extracting the `Math.random() < 0.5` isn't really my goal here. I'd like to be able to know the value inside the loop. So, say I wanted to roll a die, and the goal is to not roll a 6, and I wanted to print out the value each time, how would you do it?

Comment: If your goal is different, you'd write a different function that returns a different type of value. To "not roll a 6" would be `roll() != 6` where `roll()` produces values in the range of 1 through 6 inclusive.